# R How do I add multiple annotations to same field of data.frame without overwriting?

Tags: r, append, dataframe

(1) I have the following data.frame:

```
    queryHits subjectHits 
     <integer>   <integer> 
 1           1         246 
 2           1         247 
 3           1         248 
 4           1         249 
 5           1         250
```

I have two data frames:

(2) Dataset one with annotation data:

```
                                  celltype
                               <character>
1       Non-Gene Associated|Reg.Feats K562
2              Unclassified|Reg.Feats NHEK
3        Gene Associated|Reg.Feats GM06990
4         Unclassified|Reg.Feats MultiCell
5              Unclassified|Reg.Feats HSMM
```

(3) Dataset two which needs to be annotated

```
                      annotation
                     <character>
1   Unclassified|Reg.Feats HUVEC
2   Unclassified|Reg.Feats HUVEC
3   Unclassified|Reg.Feats HUVEC
4   Unclassified|Reg.Feats HUVEC
5   Unclassified|Reg.Feats HUVEC
```

(1) Tells me what annotation from (2) needs to be added where in (3). (e.g. the subset of (1) tells us that the annotations from lines 246, 247, 248, 249, 250 in (2) all need to be added to line 1 of (3)). My problem is that (3) needs to have multiple annotations in the same field. Right now I have only been able to make a solution where the annotations in (3) gets overwritten everytime a new annotation is added to it.

```
mcols(vcfData)$annotation[queryHits(hits)] <- mcols(encodeData)$celltype[subjectHits(hits)]
```

Do you have a smart solution to how multiple annotations can be added to the same field?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to reproduce without a full example, but you could try adding the annotation as a list variable.

For example,

```
n = c(2, 3, 5) 
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc", "dd", "ee") 

s <- data.frame(s)
s$n <- list(n)

> s
   s       n
1 aa 2, 3, 5
2 bb 2, 3, 5
3 cc 2, 3, 5
4 dd 2, 3, 5
5 ee 2, 3, 5
```

Comment: Thanks, I made a for-loop and then added lists of annotations to each entry in the data.frame :)